# Prove: If $G$ and $H$ are disjoint $G_{\delta}$, then there exists an $F_{\sigma}$ set $B$ such that $H\subseteq B$ and $B\cap G=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Problem. Prove: If $G$ and $H$ are disjoint  $G_{\delta}$ sets, then there exists an $F_{\sigma}$ set $B$ such  that $H\subseteq B$ and $B\cap G=\emptyset$. Please HELP. Thank you..

Comment: Any assumptions on the space? Anything that you tried and failed to do? The proof writing tag is when you have the idea but formulating the proof is problematic. You seem to be asking for the mathematics behind the solution.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. I dont know where to start.. Our Professor only assign this topic to read and do the following exercises in Djugundji Book..Can you share with me the sketch of the proof.thank you.

Comment: @ Ricardo Cervantes. Please Help.

Comment: What can you say about the complement of a $G_\delta$ set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very straightforward, so I don’t want to say much, but here’s a HINT: show that the complement of any $G_\delta$ set is an $F_\sigma$ set. (By the way, the assumption that $H$ is a $G_\delta$ set is irrelevant: you need only know that $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set and that $G\cap H=\varnothing$.)

Comment: @Bayoy: You're very welcome.